# Query for top x elements in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models such that

```
class JobTitle(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Employer(models.Model): 
     jobtitle = models.ForeignKey(JobTitle,unique=False,null=True)
```

As you see, one employer may have many jobtitles. I try to make a query to get top 5 employers whose number of job titles is maximum

How can I achive this is Django ?

Thanks

Comment: With this model, how does one employer can have multiple job titles? and where are the rest of the fields for employer? it's just a foreign key?

Comment: @SeanEd-Man I guess he meant many `Employers` can have the same `JobTitle`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
Employer.objects.values('id').annotate(jobtitle_count=Count('jobtitle')).order_by('-jobtitle_count')[:5]
```

Comment: even better: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 11):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Employer.objects.annotate(Count('jobtitle')).order_by('-jobtitle__count')[:5]
```

Comment: You just count rows in `Employer` table. You need grouping.