# Query to fetch highest rated movie with mimimum 5 people rated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to fetch name of movie with maximum rated movie with minimum 5 people rated in django.
My code :

model.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField()

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    movie_id = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

what will be query to get movie with highest rating with minimum 5 people ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose that you make some changes to your model. Normally `ForeignKey`s do *not* end with an `id` suffix, since Django will add a "twin field" with an `_id` suffix that stores the value of the target field. Furthermore you probably better make a `ForeignKey` to the user model. If you do not specify a primary key yourself, Django will automatically add an field named `id` that is an `AutoField`, hendce there is no need to add that manually. Finally you do not need to store the `vote_count` in a field of the `Movie`, you can retrieve that by counting the number of related `Rating` objects:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete.models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Then we can retrieve the highest rated movie with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Count

higest_rated = Movie.objects.annotate(
    rating=Avg('rating__rating'),
    votes=Count('rating')
).filter(votes__gte=5).order_by('-rating').first()
```

Here the `votes__gte=5` will filter such that it will only obtain `Movie`s with five or more votes, and we order by `rating` in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the model, moving out Rating entity related fields from Watchlist and Movie.

Add the "Rate" class, and then filter by two conditions:

1. Count(Rate for the exact Movie) > minimum threshold(e.g. 5)
2. AVG(rating score for the exact Movie) > minimum threshold(e.g. 5)
   or, if you need top-rated movies, use Order by as it described [in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436937/query-for-top-x-elements-in-django)

In your case, you could use [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) and [Average](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#avg) with Watchlist.Rating field

Comment: can anyone help with the query ?