# Query to fetch highest rated x with mimimum x people rated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

model.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField()

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    movie_id = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

query to fetch top rated movie with minimum 5 people rated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, I invite you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728819/query-to-fetch-highest-rated-movie-with-mimimum-5-people-rated

Comment: You could add an minium example if you want to discuss about how to do it, or showing what your are doing and where did you get stuck so others could help

Answer (score 0):

You should read basics about [django's annotation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)
In your case, something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, F

qs = Movie.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('watchlist_set'), 
                            vote_sum=Sum('watchlist_set__rating'), 
                            rating = F('vote_sum')/F('vote_count')

    ).filter(
        vote_count__gte=5,
    ).order_by(
        '-rating'
    )
```